# Difference between tender and gentle

Tags: word-difference

What is the difference between *tender* and *gentle*? In my opinion, which comes from scenerios of movies and TV shows and which I am not sure about, tender refers to love such as mother taking care children and lovers while gentle's connotation is being polite as a gentleman to strangers or someone who is not close to us.

Comment: *Be gentle with the baby* does not connote *be polite* with the baby. Nor does *Is your wound still tender?* ask about love.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a good question and can be confusing since **tender** and **gentle** are shown as **synonyms** by many dictionaries.

For your usage:

**Tender** is related to **affection** and **feeling**

> **a mother's tender touch**
>   the **tenderness** between the owner and their pet

**Gentle** is descriptive of **temperment**, how someone acts, their behaviour

> his was always **gentle** and never angry
>   the doctor was **gentle** in treating his patients
>   the bad news was **gently** given

The **gentleness** between the lovers showed **tenderness**

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I know tender is something about affecttion.